# Rationality of $X \times \mathbb P^1$ does not imply Rationality of $X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

What is the example that $X$ is not rational but $X\times \mathbb P^1$ is? (this is called *stable rational* if I remember correctly)

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try googling? Searching for "variety which is not stably rational" gives as the first result a [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09261.pdf) which links to a paper discussing a counterexample: A. Beauville, J.-L. Colliot-Thelene, J.-J. Sansuc, Sir Peter Swinnerton-Dyer, Varietes stablement rationnelles non rationnelles. Ann. of Math, 121 (1985) 283–318.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. I tried without the key word "variety" and then did not find this...